# Simple code implementation of some architectural patterns

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I was wondering if anyone knew of any ***simple*** code implementations of the following architectural patterns (in Java or C#):

```
* Blackboard (passive & active)
* Presentation Abstraction Control (PAC)
* MVC
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The following link will provide a java implementation of the Presentation Abstraction Control pattern:

http://www.vico.org/pages/PatronsDisseny/Pattern%20Presentation%20Abstra/

Following is an article on the MVC pattern:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/MVC_intro12122005162329PM/MVC_intro.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Martin Fowler has some reasonable simple examples along with explanatory text for MVC patterns in the links on this page:
http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/ModelViewPresenter.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a multitude of examples in various languages just waiting for you at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science))...